# How to integrate purchased theme with rails 5 application ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes, integrate

I have purchased flatkit theme from themeforst but I don't know how to integrate purchased theme with rails 5 application ?

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific, less open ended question.

Comment: This is not a question you can ask here. If you don't know how you don't know rails. If you know, you can split theme parts into view and inject ruby code where you need data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution.

Step1: Place the asset files in vendor directory.

Step2: Import required css & scss file by add require statement in application.css

ex) *=require assets/animate.css/animate.min.css

note: animate.min.css stored in location app-directory/vendor/assets/animate.css

step3: Import required js files by add require statement in application.js

ex) //= require html/scripts/ui-nav.js

note: ui-nav.js stored in location app-dir/vendor/html/scripts/ui-nav.js

Step4: Configure asset path by add following statement in assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor')

Now you can access your theme future.